# VBA run-time error 5 when deleting SQL Connections

Tags: sql-server, vba

I'm writing a macro that will create a static file based on a file connected to the SQL Server. It should refresh the Excel file, delete all connections to the SQL server, save it out as a new file with the date appended to the end and then close the existing file.

The issue I'm running into is that when I clear the connections I get a run-time error 5 "Invalid Call or argument". The odd thing is that it ran perfectly last night and this morning and then this error started popping up seemingly out of nowhere. I don't think I made any changes to the file that would have caused this to happen so I'm pretty baffled.

The debugger highlights the loop clearing connections here:

```
Do While ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count > 0
ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count).Delete
Loop
```

Here's my code:

```
Sub CreateTemplate()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim NewName As String

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Do While ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count > 0
ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count).Delete
Loop

FilePath = "C:\": NewName = FilePath & "File" & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & ".xlsb"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName, FileFormat _
:=xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False

    MsgBox "Your new template is saved with today's date appended"

    ActiveWorkbook.Close False


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using `Option Base 1`?  If not, your .Item may be missing the 0 connection and be failing on the Count + 1 connection.

Comment: Yeah when I test with option base 1 I get the same error.

Comment: When you get the error and are in debug mode, using the Immediate Window, what is the value of ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count is 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have a data model or pivot table based on a data model (such as PowerPivot).  In that case, try using this code instead:

```
Dim xConnect As Object
For Each xConnect In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
If xConnect.Name <> "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then xConnect.Delete
Next xConnect
```